# cascade not including table data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
create type person_type2 as object
( first_name varchar(30),
last_name varchar(30),
age number(3) )
/
 create table person_table2 of person_type2
/
insert into person_table2
values (person_type2 ('john', 'doe', 50))
/
alter type person_type2
add attribute (dob date),
drop attribute age
cascade not including table data
/
```

I don't understand what is "cascade not including table data" used for? I ran the script and couldn't see any differences with or without cascade not include statement, I mean everything is like what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

The statement   `cascade not including table data` would make a difference when you try to `alter` a table column datatype.

The `CASCADE` option for `ALTER TYPE` propagates a type change to dependent `types` and `tables`. `CASCADE` itself has options that let you choose whether to `convert table data` to the `new type format` as part of the propagation: the option `INCLUDING TABLE DATA` converts the `data`; the option `NOT INCLUDING TABLE DATA` does not convert it. By default, the `CASCADE` option converts the data. In any case, table data is always returned in the format of the latest type version. If the table data is stored in the format of an earlier type version, Oracle converts the data to the format of the latest version before returning it, even though the format in which the data is actually stored is not changed until the data is rewritten.

In you case since you are just dropping a attribute and adding a new its really `not` usable here.

Read more at :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjadv.htm#ADOBJ006